# PyInstaller - how to retain default site packages locations

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I've used PyInstaller to create a distribution of my application (simply using `pyinstaller --distpath=some\path\dist --workpath=some\path\ my_app.py`).

My application allows loading user scripts at runtime (GUI allows selecting a Python file) using `importlib`.

The issue is that these user scripts can import third party libraries found in the usual Python site-packages location. However, PyInstaller seems to change the locations used (as evidenced by printing `sys.path`) to be the location where the exe is run from. I understand this is needed for the exe to work.

Is there a way for PyInstaller to keep reference to the user's site packages whilst still adding the required paths for the exe to work?